# simple autoslider with javascript but Setinterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i write some codes for my simple slider but some things run wrong

i want to reset `canvasHeight`

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
    function myTimer() {

            img.css({'top':- (height -canvasHeight) })  
            canvasHeight+=100
            var top = img.css('top')

            if (top == '0px'){
                myStopFunction()
                img.css({'top':-height})
                canvasHeight = 0
                canvasHeight+=100
                height = new $('img').height() - canvasHeight;
                setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
            } 
    }

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/n1uzy4u3/**

Comment: Put your code directly in the question (a  *supporting* fiddle is good). Explain what you are trying to achieve. Explain what doesn't work.

Comment: What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the `setInterval` that restarts it to the `myVar` variable, so the next time you try to clear it, it's still using the interval ID from the original call. This causes multiple intervals to be running, and therefore multiple, competing calls of your function.

Also, you've got a bunch of implicit global vars, because you're missing the comma separator.

```js
var img = $('img'),
  time = 2000,
  top = img.css('top'),
  canvasHeight = 100,
  height = $('img').height() - canvasHeight;

img.css({
  'top': -height
})

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  img.css({ 'top': -(height - canvasHeight) })
  canvasHeight += 100
  var top = img.css('top')

  if (top == '0px') {
    myStopFunction()
    img.css({ 'top': -height })
    canvasHeight = 0
    canvasHeight += 100
    height = new $('img').height() - canvasHeight;
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
  }
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scene {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #996711;
}

.scene-element {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scene-element img {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .8s;
  -o-transition: all ease .8s;
  transition: all ease .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="scene">
    <div class="scene-element">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gXKiMR/01.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also removed the anonymous functions you were passing to `setInterval`. You can just pass the actual function you're calling if there's no other code to run.